# Sorting a list of phone numbers by teleconference provider and location

Tags: functional-programming, swift

I'm looking to order an array of phone numbers with a primary sorting criteria of whether the teleconference provider is correct and a secondary criteria of whether the the location of the phone number matches the location of the user.

Example:

If `UserLocation = US`, `meetingProvider = AT&T`, the order should be:

1. US AT&T Number
2. UK AT&T Number
3. US Unknown number
4. UK Unknown number
5. US Webex number
6. UK Webex number

I've made two solutions for this problem. The sort function used in my 2nd attempt appears to be the function to use but I find the long winded closures impact readability. Although filtering repeatedly seems somewhat inefficient. With readability in mind, how can I can improve this function and which attempt is the better way to go about this?

**1st attempt**

```
///Orders parsed numbers by correctProvider -> unknownProvider -> incorrectProvider. If the users location can be idenitified we then order these subsets so the numbers for the users location are on top.
private static func sortParsedNumbers(meeting: Meeting) -> [String] {
    let unknownProviderNumbers = meeting.phoneNumbers.filter { ConferenceNumberDirectory.findProvider(forNumber: $0) == .unknown }
    var correctProviderNumbers = meeting.phoneNumbers.filter { ConferenceNumberDirectory.findProvider(forNumber: $0) == meeting.conferenceProvider }
    let incorrectProviderNumbers = meeting.phoneNumbers.filter { !unknownProviderNumbers.contains($0) && !correctProviderNumbers.contains($0) }

    if let userCountry = getUserLocation() {
        let userAndNumberLocationMatch = {ConferenceNumberDirectory.findCountryISOCodes(forNumber: $0).contains(userCountry)}
        let matchingLocationNumbers = correctProviderNumbers.filter(userAndNumberLocationMatch)
        let nonMatchingLocationNumbers = correctProviderNumbers.filter {matchingLocationNumbers.contains($0)}
        correctProviderNumbers = matchingLocationNumbers + nonMatchingLocationNumbers
    }
    return correctProviderNumbers + unknownProviderNumbers + incorrectProviderNumbers
```

**2nd attempt**

```
///Orders parsed numbers by correctProvider -> unknownProvider -> incorrectProvider. If the users location can be idenitified we then order these subsets so the numbers for the users location are on top.
    private static func sortParsedNumbers(meeting: Meeting) -> [String] {

    guard let userCountry = getUserLocation() else {
        let numbersOrderedByProvider = meeting.phoneNumbers.sorted {element,_ in ConferenceNumberDirectory.findProvider(forNumber: element) == .unknown }
            .sorted {element,_ in ConferenceNumberDirectory.findProvider(forNumber: element) == meeting.conferenceProvider}
        return numbersOrderedByProvider
    }

    let numbersOrderedByLocation = meeting.phoneNumbers.sorted(by: {x,_ -> Bool in ConferenceNumberDirectory.findCountryISOCodes(forNumber: x).contains(userCountry)} )
    let numbersOrderedByLocationAndProvider = numbersOrderedByLocation.sorted {ConferenceNumberDirectory.findProvider(forNumber: $0) == .unknown && ConferenceNumberDirectory.findProvider(forNumber: $1) != .unknown }
        .sorted {ConferenceNumberDirectory.findProvider(forNumber: $0) == meeting.conferenceProvider && ConferenceNumberDirectory.findProvider(forNumber: $1) != meeting.conferenceProvider}
    return numbersOrderedByLocationAndProvider
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your first attempt

That seems to be a correct implementation, but the same array `meeting.phoneNumbers`
is filtered repeatedly, which is not very efficient. You could improve it by 
traversing the array once and assign each phone number to one of the four arrays:

```
func sortParsedNumbers(meeting: Meeting) -> [String] {

    var unknownProviderNumbers: [String] = []
    var incorrectProviderNumbers: [String] = []
    var correctProviderNumbers: [String] = []
    var matchingLocationNumbers: [String] = []

    let userCountry = getUserLocation()
    for phoneNumber in meeting.phoneNumbers {
        // ... append `phoneNumber` to one of the four arrays ...
    }

    return matchingLocationNumbers + correctProviderNumbers + incorrectProviderNumbers + unknownProviderNumbers
}
```

But this does not scale well if more sorting criteria are added.
Which leads us to

#### Your second attempt

There are two problems. First, you sort the arrays with comparison functions like this:

```
meeting.phoneNumbers.sorted { element, _ in
    someBooleanPredicate(element)
}
```

But the [`sorted(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted)
method requires that the given predicate is a "*strict weak ordering* over the elements",
in particular that

- `areInIncreasingOrder(a, a)` is always false. (Irreflexivity)

and that condition is violated in your code.

Second, you chain multiple `sorted(by:)` calls. But the `sorted()` method
is not *stable,* which means that the later sort can destroy the result of the
previous sorts.

For both reasons, your code *may* give correct results, but you cannot rely on it.

So (unless you have a stable sort method, which the Swift standard library does not
yet provide), a multi-level sort must be done with a *single* call to `sorted(by:)`.

Let's start with an example: Assume that you have a `Person` type with `firstName`
and `lastName` properties, then

```
persons.sort(by: { (lhs, rhs) in
    if lhs.lastName != rhs.lastName {
        return lhs.lastName < rhs.lastName
    }
    return lhs.firstName < rhs.firstName
})
```

would be a correct way of sorting an array with respect to the last name first,
and with respect to the first name second. This can be simplified to

```
persons.sort(by: { (lhs, rhs) in
    return (lhs.firstName, lhs.lastName) < (rhs.firstName, rhs.lastName)
})
```

because the compiler automatically creates a `<` operator for tuples of
comparable elements, implementing the lexicographical order.

In your case we have two criteria as well: provider and location. First we need some
type to describe and compare the desired sorting order for both criteria.
That could be just an `Int`, but an integer-based `enum` describes the intention more clearly:

```
enum ProviderStatus: Int, Comparable {
    case known
    case unknown
    case correct

    static func <(lhs: ProviderStatus, rhs: ProviderStatus) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
}

enum LocationStatus: Int, Comparable {
    case notMatching
    case matching

    static func <(lhs: LocationStatus, rhs: LocationStatus) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
}
```

Then you can compute a tuple describing the sorting order for each phone
number, and sort the numbers accordingly:

```
func sortParsedNumbers(meeting: Meeting) -> [String] {

    let userCountry = getUserLocation()

    func sortOrder(phoneNumber: String) -> (ProviderStatus, LocationStatus) {
        let providerStatus = ...
        let locationStatus = ...
        return (providerStatus, locationStatus)
    }

    return meeting.phoneNumbers.sorted(by: { (lhs, rhs) in
        sortOrder(phoneNumber: lhs) < sortOrder(phoneNumber: rhs)
    })
}
```

Adding more sorting criteria is straightforward with this approach.

A possible disadvantage is that `sortOrder()` can be called multiple times for the
same phone number during the sorting process. That can be avoided at the expense
of additional storage:

```
    return meeting.phoneNumbers
     .map { ($0, sortOrder(phoneNumber: $0))}
     .sorted { $1.1 > $0.1 }
     .map { $0.0 }
```

The return expression maps each phone number to a (number, sortOrder) pair,
sorts the pairs according to the sort order, and finally extracts the phone number
again. This guarantees that the `sortOrder()` function is called only once
for each phone number.